# Viewer not reading certain data from 3ds Max

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, 3dsmax

Kindly see this image for the reference:

[image]

Seems like adding a `Opacity` map with an Aplha channel output is not working, as this isn't reflected in the SVF file after the translation of the `.MAX` file containing Opacity maps. Is Opacity maps supported with 3ds Max for the Forge Viewer?

Comment: I'm checking that and will get back to you...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it

Comment: Does anybody know whether there's any update to this question?

Answer (score 0):

As 3dsMax supports many different image formats, the best is to use `.JPG` and `.PNG` (for transparent), which should help compatibility. This is an area that our development team is working to improve (as of July 2019).